# Highlighting labels of undefined citations?

Tags: bibliographies, highlighting, debugging

I am wanting 'cite' entries that don't have a corresponding 'bibitem' entry to show up in red, along with the name of the missing reference label. I had found a [forum entry](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=13654) that suggested a solution, but it only displayed [?citation?]. I would prefer it to display [?nameOfMissingKey?], but I am fairly new to LaTeX, so not sure the best way to tweak this.

Any help would be appreciated.

BTW the suggested solution was:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\missingreference}{\colorbox{red}{?reference?}}
\newcommand*{\missingcitation}{\colorbox{red}{?citation?}}
\makeatletter
\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\missingreference}%
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null
  \fi}
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\missingcitation}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

This is a missing reference: \ref{somefig}.

This is a mssing citation: \cite{somebib}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You will get a note in the log file which keys are undefined. Additionally, package `showkeys` could be valuable for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

You can simply redefine a bit of the code. I highlighted the changed lines with my initials.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\missingreference}[1]{\colorbox{red}{?#1?}}%JB
\newcommand*{\missingcitation}[1]{\colorbox{red}{?#1?}}%JB
\makeatletter
\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\missingreference{#3}}%%JB
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null
  \fi}
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\missingcitation{#2}}%%JB
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

This is a missing reference: \ref{somefig}.

This is a mssing citation: \cite{somebib}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, though seem to have an issue with the '\newcommand' lines which are having issues when using the #1 value, instead of a static value.

Comment: Can you explain it more precisely?

Comment: Seems to work now. Not sure what changed. Thanks for your help.